# Count tabs with same title in Firefox add-on using Add-on SDK

Tags: firefox, sdk, tabs

I am trying to count firefox tabs with same specific title (like Google title) on Firefox add-on builder.

I know about

```
var tabs = require("tabs");
for each (var tab in tabs)
```

but how to get count number of tabs with same name? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How do you get the titles of the tabs? Is this possible? Once you've worked that out, declare an object for storing title counts, where the title is the property.

```
ttabs_obj = ttabs_obj || {}; // your retrieved tabs
titles_count = titles_count || {};
ttabs_obj.forEach(function(tab, titles_count){
    title = ''; //get title from tab here, replacing characters invalid in property names with '_'
    if (!(title in titles_count)) {
        titles_count[title] = 0;
    }
    titles_count[title] += 1;
});
```

Comment: add-on sdk use javascript. This code can not be used in javascript environment.

Comment: Are you using jQuery by any chance, or plain Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
//Set up namespace
var app={};
app.tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

//Takes an array and returns an object.
//In this case, keys are tab titles and values are tab counts.
app.summarize=function(arr){
    return arr.reduce(function(memo,item){
        if (typeof memo[item]==='undefined'){
             memo[item]=1;   
        }
        else{
            memo[item]++;           
        }
        return memo;
    },{});
};


//Whenever a tab loads, recalculate and output to console
//Need to enable console logging:
app.tabs.on('ready',function(){
    //app.tabs is a pseudo-array. Convert to array
    var tabsArr=Array.prototype.slice.call(app.tabs);
    var tabsTitles=tabsArr.map(function(tab){
        return tab.title;
    });
    console.log(app.summarize(tabsTitles));
});
```

The documentation for tabs is here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs

There were two problems: getting tab titles and getting the number of occurrences of each tab title. For getting tab titles, see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs

For getting the number of occurrences of each item in an array, see:
http://jsfiddle.net/cz2SG/

Note that in order to see the console logging you need to enable it:
https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2013/03/27/changes-to-console-log-behaviour-in-sdk-1-14/